# Linearlayout gravity issue?

Tags: android, android-layout

İ have problem about linear layout.  I think something is wierd.All of them same layout but back button moving related icon buton.I want to fit back button on the left side and btn_header_what_search_user button want to right site.But they are moving related icon(center icon).Why? and how can I back button on the left side.

[image]

my code:`

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="44dip"
              android:layout_width="320dip"
              android:background="@drawable/header_320_44dip">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="121dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:background="@drawable/icon">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="52dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back_52x32">

    </ImageView>


    <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="34dip"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:id="@+id/btn_header_what_search_user"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_nedit_nontext_64x34">
    </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 3):

You should use Relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="44dip"
              android:layout_width="320dip"
              android:background="@drawable/header_320_44dip">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="121dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
            android:background="@drawable/icon">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="52dip"
            android:layout_height="32dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back_52x32">

    </ImageView>


    <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="34dip"
            android:layout_width="64dip"
            android:id="@+id/btn_header_what_search_user"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
android:layout_alignParentright="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_nedit_nontext_64x34">
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `LinearLayout` does not work well with gravities along it's main direction (that is, a horizontal LinearLayout does not support left,right or center_horizontal, and a vertical top,bottom or center_vertical).
You could instead try a `RelativeLayout` and using the `layout_alignParentLeft`/`layout_alignParentRight` attributes (or any of the other available ones) to get the correct result.

Comment: so if i use linear layout anytime i can not use align? if i can use align how can i in linear layout? and my last question is why is related before added item? is it normal? i was thinking moving related 0,0 point?

Comment: Items in LinearLayout is added sequentially from left to right and top to bottom. thats why why arrangement of items in your layout got disturbed.

Comment: the different `align` attributes are unique to the `RelativeLayout`, meaning you can not use them in `LinearLayout`. `RelativeLayout` also has attributes for "toLeftOf","toRightOf","above" and "below" which can be used to position views in relation to each other. In the LinearLayout each view added appears in the order they appear in the xml, that is, your icon appears before the back button and is thus placed before it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution might be the use of layout weights. Set a total weight of 3 and then set a weight of 1 for each of the image views. This way the layout is split up in 3 parts and you should be able to adjust the gravity for each part. Something like that:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...
   android:weightSum="3" >

   <ImageView
       ...
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: what is doing weight? i was thinking if i want to percent of screen i am using this?

Comment: With weight you can dynamically split up your layouts, depending on the factors you are using. Another example using different factors, e.g. weightSum="10", an imageView with 5, and two textviews with 2 each. Just play around with it, though keep in mind to set the layout_width always to 0dp otherwise it won't work...